# Converting VBA code into Control Source for form TextBox

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count, subquery

I assume this is an easy answer but I am just not good at SQL statements and subqueries (if that's what I need).
I have a button that takes a value from a record in a continuous form (me.ProdNum) and gets a recordset.  It displays the results of that record set in a MsgBox (code removed for simplicity).

Objective: I'd like to report "totalsupp.recordset" on each record in a textbox.

I assume I need a SELECT COUNT(subquery), but I can't get the syntax correct.  [PNUM] and ProdNum are strings

```
Private Sub MultSupp_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim totalsupp As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

Set totalsupp = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qryKANBAN_Suppliers WHERE [PNUM] = '" & Me.ProdNum & "'")

Debug.Print totalsupp.RecordCount

Set totalsup = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Setting UNBOUND textbox Value with VBA Sub will show the same result for every record. Either have textbox expression call a VBA custom Function or use DCount(). If you want to save calculated result to table field, that is different matter. Really should not save this aggregate data.

Comment: In fact, VBA could use DCount() instead of opening recordset object. `Debug.Print DCount("*", "qryKANBAN_Suppliers", "PNUM='" & Me.ProdNum & "'")`. But again, Sub setting UNBOUND textbox Value will show same result for all records. For dynamic result, just put that DCount() in textbox ControlSource (without the Me. prefix).

Comment: The SQL would be `SELECT Count(*) AS Cnt FROM qryKANBAN_Suppliers WHERE [PNUM]='" & Me.ProdNum & "'")`. Then reference Cnt field: `Debug.Print rs!Cnt`.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of DCount...  That worked perfectly!  Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in the comments about using DCount.  I get so confused about all the double quotes and single quotes...

```
=DCount("*","qryKANBAN_Suppliers","PNUM='" & [ProdNum] & "'")
```